# Where do I install Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am in the beginning phase of trying out Laravel. I downloaded composer and have the Laravel installer on my web server. I want to just create a website with a CMS using Laravel 5 just so I can get a solid understanding of it. I am trying to figure out where to install the files. The docs say to install it in a directory using this command: "Laravel new ". This is where I am a little confused. Wouldn't I want this in the root directory of the website I will be creating? I tried to install it there but it doesn't work.

Where do I install the files so I can use it do build a CMS?

Comment: check with this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlwiPRsmP7M

Comment: Install it elsewhere, and then set your webserver root in your webserver configuration to point to the newly installed Laravel's public folder

Answer (score 1):

Basically you install laravel from composer, and point the root of your webserver to /public directory.

Comment: This is correct.  Just put it in a subdirectory on your webserver.